# Preload a background image on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-image

I created a slideshow that uses an image for the div background and then as the slides increment the background-image value is updated:

```
<div id="imageBoxContainer" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>');">


function incrementSlide(){
    $('#imageBoxContainer').css("background-image", "url(" + theNextSlide + ")");
}
```

The issue is, that when the background-image changes, it is white for a couple seconds before the image fully loads.

Is it possible to preload the background images using the above architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve it with something similar to your approach. Just add div or image elements (as many as your background images are) with background or src using your images. But make these elements invisible so they would not display. Then all the images will be cached and your js will work with no delay.

```
<?php foreach($image_url as $image) {?>
<div class="imageBoxContainerCache" style="visibility: hidden; background-image: url('<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>');">
<?php } ?>


function incrementSlide(){
    $('#imageBoxContainer').css("background-image", "url(" + theNextSlide + ")");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @krasipenkov. I found a solution with jQuery preload function.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the preload function with jQuery:

```
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}

// Usage:

$(['img1.jpg','img2.jpg','img3.jpg']).preload();
```

Working like a charm it seems!